# A 3-D ODE linear system solved by matrix exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-exponential

I am trying to solve the following linear system:
$$X'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}X.$$

I'd like to use the exponential of the matrix, called $A$, so I've calculated
$$A^{2k}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\2k&2k&1\end{pmatrix},\qquad A^{2k+1}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\2k+1&2k+1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then,
$$\exp(A)=\begin{pmatrix}e/2&e/2&0\\e/2&e/2&0\\e&e&e\end{pmatrix},$$

following that
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^t/2&e^t/2&0\\e^t/2&e^t/2&0\\e^t&e^t&e^t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{pmatrix}.$$

But so $z'=z$, and I should have $z'=x+y+z.$

What is the error?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some error in your computations. Note that if $v_1=(0,0,1)$, $v_2=\left(\frac12,\frac12,0\right)$, and $v_3=(1,0,0)$, then $A.v_1=v_1$, $A.v_2=v_2+v_1$, and $A.v_3=-v_3$. So, if$$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac12&1\\0&\frac12&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $P$ are $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$), then$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$Therefore\begin{align}e^{At}&=P\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}t\right)P^{-1}\\&=P\begin{bmatrix}e^t&te^t&0\\0&e^t&0\\0&0&e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\cosh(t)&\sinh(t)&0\\\sinh(t)&\cosh(t)&0\\te^t&te^t&e^t\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}Therefore, if$$\bigl(x(t),y(t),z(t)\bigr)=e^{At}(x_0,y_0,z_0),$$you have $x(t)=\cosh(t)x_0+\sinh(t)y_0$, $y(t)=\sinh(t)x_0+\cosh(t)y_0$, and $z(t)=te^tx_0+te^ty_0+e^tz_0$, and then $z'=x+y+z$.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to find my error. Please, why did you do $\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}t\right)=\begin{bmatrix}e^t&te^t&0\\0&e^t&0\\0&0&e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}t\right)=\begin{bmatrix}e^t&e^t&0\\0&e^t&0\\0&0&e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$? More than that, the exponential of a matrix is given by power series, isn't? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential Thank you!

Comment: Because$$\begin{bmatrix}t&t&0\\0&t&0\\0&0&-t\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}t^n&nt^n&0\\0&t^n&0\\0&0&(-1)^nt^n\end{bmatrix}$$and\begin{align}t+\frac{2t^2}{2!}+\frac{3t^3}{3!}+\cdots&=t\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)\\&=te^t.\end{align}

Comment: I understand, thank you!!

Comment: Please, don't care if I ask only one more thing. I've found my error, but have one last question: the sum of the matrix exponential is from $n=0$. So, why don't I have $$1+t+\dfrac{2t^2}{2!}+\dfrac{3t^2}{3!}+...=1+te^t$$?

Comment: Because $e^{At}=\operatorname{Id}+At+\frac12(At)^2+\frac1{3!}(At)^2+\cdots$ and the second entry of the first line of the identity matrix is $0$. So, the second entry of the first line of $e^{At}$ is $\color{red}0+t+\frac{2t^2}{2!}+\frac{3t^3}{3!}+\cdots$

Comment: Oh, really, $A^0$ is not the matrix filled with ones, but the identity! Of course. Thank you really really much.